# Discord.js modal submission timing out/ not being caught

Tags: javascript, discord.js, modal-dialog, timeout, bots

I'm currently trying to make a modal based ordering system where upon creating a ticket, an Embed with Button is sent and the button starts a Modal that picks up the order. All works fine till this point, where pressing the "submit" button it times out and gives me the error "Something went wrong. Try again"

**Embed + Button creation:**

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => { 
    if (message.author.id === '149565760950239232' && message.channel.name.includes('ticket')) {     
        
        const tanksEmbed = new EmbedBuilder() 
        .setColor(0xb054c8)
        .setTitle('First steps to get your tank souls:')
        .setDescription('Press the button below to submit your order.')
        .setFooter({ text: 'Contact Aldoraz#0001 for issues and questions' })
       
       const tanksButton = new ActionRowBuilder() 
        .addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('tanks_button')
                .setLabel('Submit Tank Order')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
                .setEmoji('')
                .setDisabled(false),
        );

        message.channel.send({
            embeds: [tanksEmbed],
            components: [tanksButton]
        });
    }
});
```

**Modal creation upon button click**

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {  Button
    if (!interaction.isButton() || !interaction.customId === 'tanks_button') return;
    console.log(`[${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}] Button pressed!`);

    const TankForm = new ModalBuilder()
        .setCustomId('tankform')
        .setTitle('First steps to buy M3 Tank Souls')

    const IGN = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('minecraft_ign')
            .setLabel('IGN')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
            .setPlaceholder('Write your Minecraft IGN here!')
            .setRequired(true),
            );
        
    const Weapon = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            new SelectMenuBuilder()
                .setCustomId('weapon_type')
                .setPlaceholder('Soul Weapon Type')
                .addOptions( //list of options
                   );

    const ownedWeapon = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            new SelectMenuBuilder()
                .setCustomId('owned_weapon')
                .setPlaceholder('Do you own the weapon already?')
                .addOptions( //list of options
                 );

    const ownedTanks = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            new SelectMenuBuilder()
                .setCustomId('owned_tanks')
                .setPlaceholder('How many souls are on ther weapon?')
                .addOptions( //list of options
                  );

    const wantedTanks = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
            new SelectMenuBuilder()
                .setCustomId('wanted_tanks')
                .setPlaceholder('How many M3 Tanks do you want applied?')
                .addOptions( //list of options
                    );
        
    TankForm.addComponents(IGN, Weapon, ownedWeapon, ownedTanks, wantedTanks);
        
    interaction.showModal(TankForm);
});
```

**Picking up Modal and logging content**

```js
client.on('modalSubmit', async (modal) => {
    if (!modal.customId === 'tankform') return;
    await modal.reply({ content: 'Your order was received successfully!', ephemeral: true });
    const IGN = modal.getTextInputValue('minecraft_ign');
    const Weapon = modal.getSelectMenuValue('weapon_type');
    const ownedWeapon = modal.getSelectMenuValue('owned_weapon');
    const ownedTanks = modal.getSelectMenuValue('owned_tanks');
    const wantedTanks = modal.getSelectMenuValue('wanted_tanks');
    console.log({IGN, Weapon, ownedWeapon, ownedTanks, wantedTanks})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your `if` statement. What you probably think it is doing is checking if it doesn't equal `"tankform"`. In fact, you are checking if `false` is equal to it, since `!` is converting the `modal.customId` to a boolean. The right operator is the [strict inequality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality) (`!==`) operator

```js
if (modal.customId !== "tankform") return;
```